# Getting ERROR: unknown key name ‘docinfo’ on sharetribe installation

Tags: thinking-sphinx, sharetribe

I've been struggling to run `bundle exec rake ts:index` in my `sharetribe` project. It's returning an error:

```
rony@ronyMacMini sharetribe % bundle exec rake ts:index
Generating configuration to /Users/rony/Documents/freelensia Ofc/sharetribe/config/development.sphinx.conf
DEBUG    (1.0ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
DEBUG   ↳ app/indices/custom_field_value_index.rb:8
DEBUG   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Destroy (4.2ms)  DELETE FROM `delayed_jobs` WHERE (handler LIKE ('--- !ruby/object:ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::%') AND locked_at IS NULL AND locked_by IS NULL AND failed_at IS NULL)
DEBUG   ↳ /Users/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/rake:23
Sphinx 3.3.1 (commit b72d67bc)
Copyright (c) 2001-2020, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/Users/rony/Documents/abc/sharetribe/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
ERROR: unknown key name 'docinfo' in /Users/rony/Documents/abc/sharetribe/config/development.sphinx.conf line 40 col 10.
FATAL: failed to parse config file '/Users/rony/Documents/abc/sharetribe/config/development.sphinx.conf'

The Sphinx indexing command failed:
  Command: indexer --config "/Users/rony/Documents/abc/sharetribe/config/development.sphinx.conf" --all
  Status:  1
  Output:  See above

There may be more information about the failure in /Users/rony/Documents/abc/sharetribe/log/development.searchd.log.
```

> Note that: To install thinking-sphinx on my mac, I’ve downloaded a
> pre-built set of binaries and copy-pasted content of bin inside
> usr/local/bin.

Searched everywhere but couldn't found the solution. I'm sure I'm missing some stupid thing.

Please help me to fix it.

**Update**
Downgraded sphinx to `2.2.11`. Now another issue raised:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/mysql55/mysql/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/indexer
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      indexer
```

I think `/opt/local` is not correct system directory format for mac. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is due to recent versions of Sphinx removing the `docinfo` setting.

Which version of Thinking Sphinx is Sharetribe using? If it's 4.x, you can disable the `docinfo` settings by adding `skip_docinfo: true` to each appropriate environment in `config/thinking_sphinx.yml`. For example:

```
development:
  skip_docinfo: true
```

In Thinking Sphinx v5.0, docinfo is no longer used, but upgrading requires a bit of work with [adding callbacks to all indexed models](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/releases/tag/v5.0.0).

If you're using Thinking Sphinx v3.x, then you'll need to downgrade your version of Sphinx to v2.2.11.